# Cascading counter pulses (strobes?) in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, counter

The basic gist is I'm trying to write an audio synthesizer. The note sequencer engine is based on a "tick" of 60Hz. Each note duration is a multiple of 5 ticks, let's call this a beat (even though it's really a thirty-second note). As such, I'd like a 1-clock pulse (strobe?) every tick *and* a 1-clock pulse every beat (5 ticks). Then I can count beat pulses for note duration. For example, a note could play for 8 beats (40 ticks), then another note for 4 beats (20 ticks), etc. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to do this.

The tick pulse is pretty easy:

```vhdl
  localparam CLOCKS_PER_TICK = 415_667; // 25MHz / 60Hz
  localparam TICK_WIDTH = $clog2(CLOCKS_PER_TICK);
  reg   [TICK_WIDTH-1:0]  r_tick_counter = 0;
  reg                     r_tick_pulse = 0;
  always @(posedge i_clk) begin
    if (r_tick_counter == CLOCKS_PER_TICK) begin
      r_tick_counter <= 0;
      r_tick_pulse <= 1;
    end else begin
      r_tick_counter <= r_tick_counter + 1;
      r_tick_pulse <= 0;
    end
  end
```

The beat pulse *seems* like it should pretty straightforward: Count 5 tick pulses. However, it ends up being fairly complicated, which means I'm likely doing it wrong:

```vhdl
  localparam  TICKS_PER_BEAT = 5;
  localparam  BEAT_WIDTH = $clog2(TICKS_PER_BEAT);
  reg   [BEAT_WIDTH-1:0]  r_beat_counter = 0;
  reg                     r_beat_clk = 0;
  reg                     r_last_beat_clk = 0;
  always @(posedge i_clk) begin
    if (r_tick_pulse) begin
      if (r_beat_counter == TICKS_PER_BEAT-1) begin
        r_beat_counter <= 0;
        r_beat_clk <= ~r_beat_clk;
      end else begin
        r_beat_counter <= r_beat_counter + 1;
      end
    end
    r_last_beat_clk <= r_beat_clk;
  end
  wire r_beat_pulse = r_beat_clk != r_last_beat_clk;
```

The idea here is `r_beat_counter` counts up on every `r_tick_pulse` from `0` to `4`. However, figuring out how to get a 1-clock wide pulse seems to require making a fake "clock" `r_beat_clk` and then using `r_last_beat_clk` to effectively detect any edge (both pos and neg) in this "clock". This feels overly complicated, though. Is there some simpler way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create an edge detector — you already know where the edges are. Try something like this:

```
  localparam  TICKS_PER_BEAT = 5;
  localparam  BEAT_WIDTH = $clog2(TICKS_PER_BEAT);
  reg   [BEAT_WIDTH-1:0]  r_beat_counter = 0;
  reg                     r_beat_clk = 0;
  always @(posedge i_clk) begin
    if (r_tick_pulse) begin
      if (r_beat_counter == TICKS_PER_BEAT-1) begin
        r_beat_counter <= 0;
        r_beat_clk <= 1;
      end else begin
        r_beat_counter <= r_beat_counter + 1;
        r_beat_clk <= 0;
      end
    end
  end
  wire r_beat_pulse = r_tick_pulse & r_beat_clk;
```

Comment: Thank you! That will totally work. I think I could even get rid of `r_beat_clk` and do:

`wire r_beat_pulse = r_tick_pulse & (r_beat_counter == TICKS_PER_BEAT-1);`

Comment: BTW, do I have my terminology right here? Are these called pulses, strobes, or something else?

Comment: "Pulse" is a little too generic for me. "Strobe" or "enable" is fine -- `tick_en`, `beat_en`, etc.